# how to change permission of /etc on amazon server

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, server

I am working on amazon server(ubuntu).
While working I changed permissions of /etc directory to 777.
Now I am not able to access phpmyadmin, not able to login to server.

Please help me with this..
One option I get from google is destroy this instance and and create another. 
If I destroy this instance I will lost all my data.

Comment: Whatever you are actually trying to accomplish here, **`chmod 777` is wrong and insecure** and you should revert to the default permissions **post haste.** Then when time permits, smite the person who told you that this would be a good idea. There *cannot* be a situation where it is safe to allow random visitors to change your system by giving everyone write access to critical configuration files.

Comment: Not a programming question anyway; voting to close as off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: Instead of wasting further time, you need to spin up a new instance as this one is a lost cause. Believe me, I have tried many things in this same scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I've gotten into situations like this before I've had success by snapshotting the EBS volume for the broken instance and mounting it on to another Instance. Once the new instance has started you can log on and retrieve all of your data.

Here is a guide from Amazon on mounting a volume created from a snapshot: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-restoring-volume.html

Comment: right now I am not able to login to server using ssh

Comment: With this method you don't need to, you can do all of this in the AWS console.

Log in to the console, got to EC2, find the EBS volume for your server and take a snapshot.
Make a new instance and mount the snapshot to it.
SSH into your new instance and mount the volume like it says in the linked guide.
Now you have access to the data from the broken server.